# individual house price transactions with multiple postcodes SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, postal-code

I have a list of about 900 postcodes for each solar farm in England and Wales. I would like to find the house prices for each postcode, to see how house prices may have changed after the solar farms were implemented.

I have been given a query which gives me the HPI corresponding to each postcode, but i would like to get the individual house transactions (houses sold) in each postcode.

I am new to SPARQL and have no idea how to do a single query for all the postcodes. If anyone can help it would be great.

This is the link to searching via postcode: http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/qonsole.

Many thanks
Reece

Comment: And you tried nothing so far?

Comment: And the last example query in your link already shows you the transaction prices for a given post code - it's not clear what else you want

Answer (score 0):

There is an example query there, with transactions in a postcode. It uses a [`VALUES` clause](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#inline-data), so simply add all your postcodes to that `VALUES` clause.

<strike>Note: they store postcodes as typed literals, so you'll have to append `^^xsd:string` to each quoted value.</strike>

Add `?postcode` to the `ORDER BY` clause to make a bit more sense of the result.

Comment: thanks, worked really well. But when pasting all the postcodes with quotation marks, says the line is invalid, but if i just delete the quotation marks and then type it back, its fine. I don't want to go through every postcode typing the quotation marks, is there a resolution for this?

Comment: You don't actually need the `^^xsd:string` in there.